# Does `document.getElementById` break the function?

Tags: javascript, timer

So I am working on a pomodoro timer and can't figure out what I am doing wrong with my JS. Overview of the project is here : http://codepen.io/Ohillio/pen/wMoNWy

But the specific part of the code I am having issues with is :

```
// global variables
var min = 0;
var sec = 0;


function tick() {
 alert("Counter Started");
 sec = 59;
 min--;
 document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
 do {
  sec--
  document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = min + ":" + sec;
  setTimeout(donothing,500);
} 
  while (sec != 0);
}
```

The issue is that it seems like it ends the function after the first time through. I want the seconds to tick down to 0, but now it just evaluates to 58.

Does `document.getElementById` break the function  ?

Comment: Where has been `min` variable defined? Also, there is something missing in line 7. Turn on your JS console.

Comment: Eduardo, sorry about that. I declared them as global at the beginning of the script. Will updated the snippet.

Comment: Thanks, I see some reference errors. Must be the culprit ! Need to use the console more. Still kind of new to this haha. I'm a ~6month hobbyist

Comment: Alright, also i guess that your `setTimeout()` function should call `tick()` function itself and `min` variable shouldn't be decreased unless `sec < 0` (also `sec` should be set to `59` when this happens) in the current loop and finally `while (sec != 0 && min != 0);` should be used down there.

Comment: Thank you sir ! I clearly need to study nesting on loops and functions a bit more :) Happy New Years

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `setInterval` may be a better solution to what you're trying to do. It's going to be more accurate and easy to short circuit once you hit 0. Also, I prefer to keep the total time in seconds and only use minutes for display purposes. I've put together an example for you to review.

```
<script>
  var interval;
  var totalSeconds = 1500;

  function tick() {
    totalSeconds--;
    min = Math.floor(totalSeconds / 60);
    sec = totalSeconds % 60;
    document.getElementById('timer').innerHTML = min + ':' + sec;
    if (0 >= totalSeconds) {
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }
  interval = setInterval(tick, 1000);
</script>
```

Hope this helps and good luck!

Comment: Thank you for this demo @ohiodoug ! It helps a lot and I would up vote if my rep was higher (apparently I need to reach 15 before that happens). It honestly makes much more sense to do this with total time in seconds ( nice use of the modulo btw :) ) I think you just taught me a few things that codeacademy didn't. Happy New Years to you sir !

Comment: Don't worry about the vote, I don't answer questions for points, I answer them to help others. I'm glad this helped. Have a happy new year to you as well!

Answer (score 0):

This also should work, with 1 digit second format fix:

```
var min = 1;
var sec = 30;

function tick() {
    document.getElementById("timer").innerHTML = min + ":" + (sec.toString().length < 2 ? '0' : '') + sec;
    if(sec === 0 && min > 0) {
        min--;
        sec = 59;
        setTimeout(tick, 500);
    } else if (sec > 0) {
        sec--;
        setTimeout(tick, 500);
    } else {
        alert("Done!");
    }
}

alert("Counter Started");
tick();
```

Comment: Thank you Eduardo ! I will look at this in the AM. For now I am off to see Star Wars in 3D :D Happy New Years !